# How to declare selectors dynamically in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, getelementsbyclassname

I've repetitive variables declarations, I think they can be improved with a for-loop, but my attempt fail.

I tried a for-loop declarer for an array but my syntax doesn't work.

I've this "Working code":

```html
<div class ="menu1 item1-1"></div>
<div class ="menu1 item1-2"></div>
<div class ="menu1 item1-3"></div>
<div class ="menu1 item1-4"></div>

<div class ="menu2 item2-1"></div>
<div class ="menu2 item2-2"></div>
<div class ="menu2 item2-3"></div>
<div class ="menu2 item2-4"></div>

<div class ="menu3 item3-1"></div>
<div class ="menu3 item3-2"></div>
<div class ="menu3 item3-3"></div>
<div class ="menu3 item3-4"></div>

<div class ="menu4 item4-1"></div>
<div class ="menu4 item4-2"></div>
<div class ="menu4 item4-3"></div>
<div class ="menu4 item4-4"></div>
```

```
var menu1 = document.getElementsByClassName('menu1');
var menu2 = document.getElementsByClassName('menu2');
var menu3 = document.getElementsByClassName('menu3');
var menu4 = document.getElementsByClassName('menu4');

for (let i = 1; i < menu1.length; i++) {

    menu1[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ menu1[i].classList.add("test"); });
}
for (let i = 1; i < menu2.length; i++) {

    menu2[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ menu2[i].classList.add("test"); });
}
for (let i = 1; i < menu3.length; i++) {

    menu3[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ menu3[i].classList.add("test"); });
}
for (let i = 1; i < menu4.length; i++) {

    menu4[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ menu4[i].classList.add("test"); });
}
```

My attempt to reduce it it was this:

```
var MENU = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {

  MENU.push("menu" + i + =document.getElementsByClassName('menu' + i +));

}
for (let j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < MENU[j].length; i++) {
        MENU[j][i].addEventListener('click', function(){ MENU[j][i].classList.add("test"); });
    }
}
```

expected result:

the same result as the "Working code":

when I click on a "menu1" div:

```html
<div class ="menu1 item1-1 test"></div>
<div class ="menu1 item1-2 test"></div>
<div class ="menu1 item1-3 test"></div>
<div class ="menu1 item1-4 test"></div>

<div class ="menu2 item2-1"></div>
<div class ="menu2 item2-2"></div>
<div class ="menu2 item2-3"></div>
<div class ="menu2 item2-4"></div>

<div class ="menu3 item3-1"></div>
<div class ="menu3 item3-2"></div>
<div class ="menu3 item3-3"></div>
<div class ="menu3 item3-4"></div>

<div class ="menu4 item4-1"></div>
<div class ="menu4 item4-2"></div>
<div class ="menu4 item4-3"></div>
<div class ="menu4 item4-4"></div>
```

actual error messages:
*"Unexpected token ="*
*"Uncaught TypeError: MENU[0][i].addEventListener is not a function"*

Edit: I've found the HUGE syntax error, is fixed but I get this error now.

Edit2: My question was too open and not specific, I narrow it down and corrected some syntax suggested by comments.

Edit3: I'm trying to:

click a "menu1" element to select all "menu1" elements.
click a "menu2" element to select all "menu2" elements.
click a "menu3" element to select all "menu3" elements.
click a "menu4" element to select all "menu4" elements.

Comment: code which you are presenting have missing `+` sign after first `i` it should be something like `MENU.push("menu" + i + "=document.getElementsByClassName('menu" + i +"')");`

Comment: my other consideration is why you have so many `classes`? instead of calling classes `menu1, menu2` etc. you could have one class `menu` and if needed in your css style each class like `.menu:first-child, .menu:nth-child(2)` etc then your code would be much easier only one call to `var menus = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');` and in variable `menus` you have array of elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Something like this:

```
const selector = '';
for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  selector += `${selector ? ', ' : ''}menu${i}, panel${i}, navprev${i}, navrtrn${i}, navnext${i}`
}

document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    // check if it is a menu:
    if (event.target.matches('[class^=menu]')) {
       // a menu was clicked
    }
  });
});
```

If you don't want to change any of your other code, you can do this:

```
const classNamePrefixes = ['menu', 'panel', 'navprev', 'navrtrn', 'navnext'];
const varNameAndClassNamePrefix = classNamePrefixes.map((cnp) => {
  const varName = cnp.replace('nav', '').replace('panel', 'panl');
  return {
    varName,
    cnp
  };
});

for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  varNameAndClassNamePrefix.forEach(({ varName, cnp }) => {
     window[`${varName}${i}`] = document.getElementsByClassName(`${cnp}${i}`)
  });
}
```

Comment: I fixed the question with the HTML and a better scope, [class^=menu] wouldn't work, please read the whole question again and sorry for not being more specific at first.

Comment: @ArtRS My second example will generate the variables as you originally had them so you won't have to change anything else (it will create the `menu1`, `menu2`, `menu3`, etc. variables). Adding a property to `window` (eg: `window.menu1 = ....`) with create a global variable (you can access it just like `menu1.addEventListener....`).

Answer (score 1):

Add to each `menu` or `panl`, etc. a generic class, for example: `menu`. So that your elements would look like:

```
<div class="menu menu1"></div>
<div class="menu menu2"></div>
<div class="menu menu3"></div>
<div class="menu menu4"></div>
```

Now you can select all of the elements with a single selector.

```
var menus = document.getElementsByClassName('menu');
```

```
console.log(menus[0]); // <div class="menu menu1"></div>
console.log(menus[1]); // <div class="menu menu2"></div>
console.log(menus[2]); // <div class="menu menu3"></div>
console.log(menus[3]); // <div class="menu menu4"></div>
```

And they are stored in a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which you can loop over with a `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
    console.log(menus[i]); // Logs each <div class="menu"> element.
}
```

Check [the documentation of MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to see more examples on how to use the `getElementsByClassName` method.

Comment: This idea doesn't apply, I added the HTML for better understanding of the question, sorry for not adding it before.

Comment: So you want to select *all* of the `menu` elements at once?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I want to select all the "menu1" elements when I click a "menu1" element. I edited the post again, I'm trying to improve my questions to explain better the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you just give them another special **attribute** juste like `<div class="whatever" specialAttribute>Some Html content</div>` ? and then use the selector just like `const selectors=document.querySelectorAll("[specialAttribute]");`

Comment: I'm already using a special attribute. I fixed the question with the HTML and a better scope, please read the whole question again and sorry for not being more specific at first.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the item to the ordinal position in the index it's a lot easier.

```
  MENU[i] = document.getElementsByClassName('menu" + i);
```

Then MENU[1] will be the reference to the first element, etc.

Comment: I fixed the question with the HTML and a better scope, MENU[i] wouldn't work, please read the whole question again and sorry for not being more specific at first.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be pushing strings, just push the result of calling the function.

```
MENU.push(document.getElementsByClassName('menu' + i));
```

Note that array indexes start at `0`. So `MENU[0]` will contain the elements with class `menu1`, and so on.

Comment: You should probably mention that the loop starts at `0` and the class names start at `1`.

Comment: I fixed the question with the HTML and a better scope, MENU[0] wouldn't work, please read the whole question again and sorry for not being more specific at first.